# Convert struct to byte array and read this via implementing `std::io::Read` trait

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement `std::io::Read` trait for a struct.

**My objective is to convert obj to byte array and read it through the implementation of Read trait.**

Following is the code I have written so far.

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use std::io::Error;
use std::io::Read;
use std::vec::Vec;
use std::str;

use super::{Chain, Transaction};

// The struct I need to convert to byte array and add the Read impl.

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Block {
    index: u64,
    timestamp: DateTime<Utc>,
    transactions: Vec<Transaction>,
    proof: i64,
    previous_hash: String,
}

// The Read trait implementation for Block

impl Read for Block {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> std::result::Result<usize, Error> {
        let bytes: &[u8] = unsafe { any_as_u8_slice(&self) };
        buf.clone_from_slice(bytes);
        Ok(bytes.len())
    }
}

// Function that converts to byte array. (found on stackoverflow)

unsafe fn any_as_u8_slice<T: Sized>(p: &T) -> &[u8] {
    ::std::slice::from_raw_parts((p as *const T) as *const u8, ::std::mem::size_of::<T>())
}
```

I get an error when I execute the code this way.

```
let mut buffer: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
let result = block.read(buffer.as_mut());
```

ERROR

> thread 'main' panicked at 'destination and source slices have
> different lengths',
> /Users/harsh/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/slice/mod.rs:2554:9

I am new to Rust, trying to learn by porting another program in Rust.

**How do I copy &[u8] to another &mut [u8] which is a vec. (Fix the Read impl for Block)?**

And is there a better way to do this?
**Convert object to byte array and return it from the Read implementation.**

Comment: TLDR, but seems [bincode](https://crates.io/crates/bincode) may help.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? Reading the raw bytes from a `Block` won't contain the contents of `transactions` or `previous_hash`.

Comment: Also `&[u8]` already implements `Read` you can use that instead. Trying to implement `Read` directly on the contents like this would be awkward at best since a `Read`er must keep track of what has been read and what hasn't.

Comment: Yes. I noticed that. Thanks. I am trying bincode to figure this out. Thanks! @kmdreko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few different problems here:

- What you're trying to do here won't be sound in general. Rust structs might include padding bytes or otherwise initialized bytes, which means that reading them from a `[u8]` is undefined behavior. The name for what you're trying to do here is a [Transmute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/transmutes.html) and they are famously *very* difficult to do correctly.
- It's not clear to me why specifically you're doing this in terms of the `Read` trait. `Read` is generally for i/o devices, like files or `stdin`, or in-memory buffers that behave like i/o devices. Even if we assume that a direct, inplace transmute to a byte slice is appropriate here, it would make more sense to just have a method on `Block` resembling `fn as_byte_slice(&self) -> &[u8] { ... }`.
- Even if we set aside the above issues, it's still not clear to me that you're going to get the outcome you expect. Transmuting a struct to a byte array will convert only the raw bytes in the struct, which will work fine for primitive types like `u64`, but for types like `Vec<T>` and `String` will only return the underlying pointer to the allocated storage.

I'm guessing that what you actually want to have happen here is that all of the contents of the `Block`– including the list of `transactions` and the `previous_hash`– be converted into the byte slice. This is called **serialization**, and the de-facto way to do it in Rust is with [serde](https://serde.rs/). Serde is an abstract library that connects *types* (like `Vec` and your own `Block`) to *data formats* like json and bincode.

In your question, you've said you want to "convert the [object] to a byte array". This is a bit nonspecific; it's likely that there is actually a specific *data format* into which you're suppose to convert this `Block`. Your specific application will likely describe which specific data format is in use, and you can then look into whether there already [exists](https://lib.rs/encoding) a serde `Serializer` for that data format, or whether you'll need to [write your own](https://serde.rs/impl-serializer.html).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, you are correct. I was able to find the solution using `serde_json`. I forgot to get back here and post an update to my question.
Also, converting to bytes wasn't the correct approach. The serialization was the correct answer. So, I am marking your answer as accepted.